# How to display two Tablix on alternating pages when row grouping is used

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, reportbuilder

I am trying to configure a report in SSRS so that 2 Tablix display on alternating pages when group on and page break after each instance of a group are used in row group properties.

Each Tablix differs in terms of layout but they share the same dataset and row grouping (SiteID). The report currently uses a drop-down menu to determine SiteID (multiple selection)

Currently the current report page/ print order is as follows. I have named the 2 Tablix accordingly.

SiteID A Cover Sheet - SiteID B Cover Sheet - SiteID A Inventory Details - SiteID B Inventory Details

Basically what I am trying to achieve is the following...

SiteID A Cover Sheet - SiteID A Inventory Details - SiteID B Cover Sheet - SiteID B Inventory Details

Is this achievable in visual studio/ RS report builder?

I have tried adjusting a few property settings in the right hand pane with no success

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you can use a LIST and Group By Site.

Then put the two tablix in the LIST item.

[image]

The list item will generate one site at a time and generate the tablix's (tablii?) for each site like you want.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much!